# Elasticsearch query - not equal

Tags: elasticsearch

I have fields called `subject.Account name` and `Target.account name`.

Sometimes both have same values like

```
"subject.Accountname" : "abc11"
"subject.Targetname" : "abc11"
```

Sometimes both values will be different like,

```
"subject.Accountname" : "xyz34"
"subject.Targetname" : "abc12"
```

Is it possible to write a query, where Target Account name Is not EQUAL to Subject Account Name, I need to have the values of that alone.

Any help much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to show your mapping in order to get an answer to that question.

Comment: You should perform that check at indexing time and create another boolean field `accountMatchesTarget: true/false` that contains that information. You queries will be much faster than having to run a script on each document to make the comparison

Comment: you want to fetch documents where Target Account name Is not EQUAL to Subject Account Name? is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes you are right :) ,please let me  know the query or how  to do it in elasticsearch

Comment: @Val , am new to ELastic Stack,how do you create a another boolean field accountMatchesTarget: true/false     , sorry if its so silly :)

Comment: When you are about to index your document, you can compare both fields and create another boolean one in your document that contains true (if both match)  or false (if both do not match). Then you can simply use a `term` query to test your boolean field.